# Acumatica: Cannot hide fields in Projects -> Summary Tab

Tags: c#, graph, tabs, customization, acumatica

I'm working on hiding all of the fields on the Summary Tab in Projects.

Most fields will hide using

```
protected void PMProject_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
```

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<PMProject.automaticReleaseAR>(cache, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<PMProject.retainageMode>(cache, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<PMProject.includeCO>(cache, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<CN.CacheExtensions.ContractExt.allowNonProjectAccountGroups>(cache, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt.usrBond>(cache, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt.usrLastDateOnJob>(cache, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt.usrBilledCompleteDate>(cache, row, false);
```

however, this code does not seem to work even though it works in elsewhere

```
//BILLING AND ALLOCATION SETTINGS
Base.Billing.AllowSelect = false;
Base.Billing.Cache.AllowSelect = false;
Base.Caches[typeof(ContractBillingSchedule)].AllowSelect = false;

PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<PX.Objects.CT.ContractBillingSchedule.type>(cache, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<ContractBillingSchedule.nextDate>(cache, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<ContractBillingSchedule.lastDate>(cache, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<PMProjectExtension.payrollWorkLocationID>(cache, row, false);

//RETAINAGE
Base.ProjectRevenueTotals.Cache.AllowSelect = false;
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<PMProjectRevenueTotal.curyRevisedAmount>(cache, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<PMProjectRevenueTotal.contractCompletedWithCOPct>(cache, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<PMProjectRevenueTotal.curyTotalRetainedAmount>(cache, row, false);
```

[image: Project Summary Tab]

Comment: Which Acumatica build you use?

Comment: 2022R1 22.112.0018

Answer (score 1):

The visibility may be changed in another event handler. To make sure this code is called after, update your parameters to add the PXRowSelected delegate and call it first.

```
    protected void PMProject_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
    {
        //call the other row selected events first before executing our code
        del?.Invoke(cache, e);
        //add our visibility code
    }
```